# Jquery - value attribute is not adding for text-box in jquery-1.4.1.min.js

Tags: jquery

I have a html table for display user list. when i click a *tr* row, that time it will find the  **td** values to text-box which is in another html table.

Assume, the given below html table is user list table,

```
<table id="tbl1" border="1">
   <tr>
       <td>name</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="tr1" style='cursor:pointer;'>
       <td>Mani</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And the given below html table for when we click a row in above html table dynamically assign the **td** values to **text-box** , like

```
<table id="tbl2">
   <tr>
       <td><input id="txt1" type="text"  /></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btnReset" value="reset" />
```

What i did, when i click a row in that table, i get a html data & assign this to a global variable & when i click `reset` button that time, just i insert the html values to the `#tbl2`.

My jquery code is given below,

```
var getHTML="";

$("#tr1").click(function(){    
   $("#txt1").val($(this).find('td').html());
   getHTML=$("#tbl2").html();
});

$("#btnReset").click(function(){
    $("#tbl2").html(getHTML);
});
```

It's working but text-box value are empty, How to i get the dynamic text-box values from html table.

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/smanimani/R77ZB/5/)

Comment: It's working in your fiddle.

Comment: It's not working.. After clicking `tr` row, When i click reset button, the text-values are empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/R77ZB/1/)

```
$("#txt1").attr('value', $(this).find('td').text());
```

instead of

```
$("#txt1").val($(this).find('td').text());
```

to add the value in your `text box` source like

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" value="Mani">
```

**Update:** [Or you may try this too](http://jsfiddle.net/R77ZB/2/).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response..! It's working fine in _jsFiddle_, but in my form it's not working.. When i add `$("#txt1").attr('value', "rrrrrr");` means the value of `rrrrrr` is displaying in text-box, but the **value** attribute is not added to  that text box...

Comment: @ManikandanSethuraju, Welcome and no it means value also added to the text-box value attr.

Comment: If i added like `$("#txt1").attr('val', "rrrrrr");` means the attribute of `val` is adding to that text box - (i checked this through firebug), but when i use `value`, its not added to that text-box..

Comment: Using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/R77ZB/1/) you'll get `<input id="txt1" type="text" value="Mani">`.

Comment: Hi, i'm using `jquery-1.4.1.min.js`.. In my form - if i add other attributes like `$("#txt1").attr('maxlength', '20');` means it's working... but when i add `value` attribute it's not adding, but displaying the value properly....

Comment: Check the source in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/R77ZB/1/) after you click the row, it's adding the `value=Mani` in the text box.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19632/discussion-between-manikandan-sethuraju-and-sheikh-heera)